# Buscar dados específicos do banco de dados no ionic 3

Tags: banco-de-dados, angularjs, ionic, sqlite

Gostaria de saber como faço para filtrar e receber apenas os dados que eu quero em cada página. meu database.ts : `getAllProdutos(){

```
return new Promise<Produto[]>((resolve, reject) => { 

  let sql = "select * from tb_produto";
  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {

    let products = [];
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      let product: Produto = { id_produto: row[0], nom_produto: row[1], val_produto: row[2] }
      products.push(product);
    });
    resolve(products);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});`
```

E meu HTML:   `<ion-card *ngFor="let produto of produtos">
              <ion-card-content>
                  <h6>Product ID: {{produto.id_produto}}</h6>
                  <h6>Product Name: {{produto.nom_produto}}</h6>
                  <h6>Product Price: {{produto.val_produto}} $</h6>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>`

Quero mostrar em cada aba do segment, apenas o conteúdo dele, porém está sempre mostrando todos em todos os segments.  Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou claro que tipo de segments você tem, mas um alternativa seria filtrar após carregar todos os produtos e criar uma variável para cada segment. Exemplo abaixo considerando um segment para produtos com price > 100.

No teu .ts

```
getAllProdutos().subscribe(produtos => {
   this.produtosSegment1 = produtos;
   this.produtosSegment2 = produtos.filter(x => return x.price > 100);
})
```

No teu .html do segment com price > 100

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let produto of produtosSegment2">
   <ion-card-content>
       <h6>Product ID: {{produto.id_produto}}</h6>
       <h6>Product Name: {{produto.nom_produto}}</h6>
       <h6>Product Price: {{produto.val_produto}} $</h6>
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```